# How would I implement an Interceptor/Filter in play framework 2.4.3 (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4

I am new to Play Framework, and I wanted to implement an interceptor or a filter that gets executed before the request goes to the Action class.

I wanted an interceptor/filter that to return HTTP error (e.g. 401), if a certain header variable is not present.

I did some googling, and I found out about the Filter (play.api.mvc.Filter) object, but the implementation returns mvc.Result, instead of Response.

> override def apply(next: (mvc.RequestHeader) => Future[mvc.Result])(request: mvc.RequestHeader)

Another solution that I can think of is to create a customized Action by extending ActionBuilder, but I'd rather not do that, If I can design a catch all functionality like Filter.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

For future reference. This is the implementation of the filter. Thanks to tryx for the help.

```
import play.api.mvc
import play.api.mvc.{RequestHeader, Filter}
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class AuthorizedFilter(requestHeader: RequestHeader) extends Filter {



  private def authorizationRequired(request: mvc.RequestHeader) = {

    request.headers.get("Authorized").
      map( authorizedValue => authorizedValue.eq("ABCDEFG")).
      getOrElse(false)

  }


  override def apply(next: (mvc.RequestHeader) => Future[mvc.Result])(request: mvc.RequestHeader) =  {
      if(authorizationRequired(request)) {

        println("YOU are authorized!!")

        next(request)

      }
      println("NOT AUTHORIZED!")
      Future {Unauthorized }
    }
}
```

Create a Filter object in the root level of the application. (/app).

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.http.HttpFilters

class Filters @Inject() (authorizedFilter: AuthorizedFilter) extends HttpFilters {

  def filters = Seq(authorizedFilter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your filter you have 2 options, you can either call `next` which passes control to the next filter or you can return a `Future[Result]` explicitly which terminates the chain. If you call `next`, eventually the filter chain will end and it will reach the action.

It sounds like you want a filter with an `apply` method like

```
apply(next: RequestHeader => Future[Result])(request: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
  if (headersok){
    next(request)
  } else {
    Future{ Unauthorized }
  }
```

}